# htaccess exclude specific folder

Tags: .htaccess

for a website I need a redirect from 
domain without www TO domain with www
and 
http TO https

The final URL has to be always https://www.myshop.com ...
I solved this successfully with this commands:

```
# if http, redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# if without www, redirect to www (301)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**The problem ist that I have to exclude a specific folder.** 
The URL to exclude is: http://www.mydomain.de/myfolder/filename.php

This means: If this URL is requestet there mustn't be a redirect.

Other tutorials I found did not work, sorry :-(

Thanks for any help and best regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a **skip redirect rule** *before* these 2 redirect rules you have:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip myfolder/filename.php from any redirects below
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /myfolder/filename\.php[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if http, redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# if without www, redirect to www (301)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that

```
RewriteEngine on

# if http, redirect to https

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# if without www, redirect to www (301)
RewriteRule ^http://www.mydomain.de/myfolder/filename.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*\filename.php$ http://www.mydomain.de/myfolder/filename.php [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like this as a first ruleset may help.  (May want to revisit those [L,R] options though.

```
# check if myfolder is contained
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[^/]*/myfolder(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# if http, redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# if without www, redirect to www (301)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```