# htaccess to exclude a specific directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I have a htaccess at the root of my site like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(?:favicon\.ico|(?:index|custom500|custom404)\.html)$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ index.php?source=$0 [L,QSA]
```

I want it to ignore those urls that contain a specific folder `folder1`. Urls will be like:

```
https://mycooldomain.com/folder1/api/rest/... //something else here
```

I have examined [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588906/htaccess-exclude-specific-folder) but I seem not able to apply it to my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# ignore request URLs that start with /folder1/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+folder1/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule \.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(?:favicon\.ico|(?:index|custom500|custom404)\.html)$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ index.php?source=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to @anubhava's answer... the only rule that *needs* to be ignored in your `.htaccess` file is the last one. So you could just add a condition to that last rule to exclude URL-paths that start `/folder1/`.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ index.php?source=$0 [L,QSA]
```

The `!` prefix on `!^/folder1/` negates the regex, so it is successful when it does *not* match. ie. when the URL-path does *not* start with `/folder1/`.